# React-Native: Exception 'Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes[#id.apps.googleusercontent.com]'

Tags: ios, exception, react-native, google-signin, url-scheme

I was trying to integrate GoogleSignin in my react-native app.

But I was getting an exception as:

'Your app is missing support for the following URL schemes[#id.apps.googleusercontent.com]' was thrown while invoking signIn on target RNGoogleSignin with params ( )

I have referred the [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) link

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

With reference to 
[react-native-google-signin iOS login issue](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/issues/247)

and answer of **tiberiumihai**

> 'For me I used in JS file #id.apps.usercontent.com instead of #id.apps.googleusercontent.com.
>
> Verify that you have the same URL schemes defined in your INFO.plist and in your js file like this:

```
await GoogleSignin.configure({
    iosClientId: '#id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    webClientId: '#id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    offlineAccess: false
  });
```

> Then in your INFO.plist, the URL should be:
>
> 'com.googleusercontent.apps.#id'
>   and 
>   '#id.apps.googleusercontent.com'
>   This solved my problem.'

**My Answer**

I need to add both the url-schemes to Info-plist file, as :

'com.googleusercontent.apps.#id'

and

'#id.apps.googleusercontent.com'

along with the bundle identifier.

This was occurring because I have added ClientId in JS file as given in the link:

```
GoogleSignin.configure({ 
iosClientId: <FROM DEVELOPER CONSOLE>, // only for iOS 
}).then(() => {
// you can now call currentUserAsync()
});
```

But it only ask to add the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID

> Configure URL types in the Info panel
>
> add a URL with scheme set to your REVERSED_CLIENT_ID (found inside the plist)

Comment: Thanks man, this answer is help me so much

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by replacing the correct file googleservice-info.plist
I was using another file from another project. please notice that your googleservice-info.plist is from a related firebase.